# ActionMailer not showing spaces in text mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, actionmailer

I have an ActionMailer controller that's supposed to send this file:

```
/user_mailer/welcome_email.text.erb
```

This is the (sample) content of the file:

```
Welcome to znood.com, <%= @user.name %>

You have successfully signed up to znood.com,
Your username is: <%= @user.email %>.

To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.

Thanks for joining and have a great day!

The Znood Team
```

[edited]
This is the code in the controller:

```
def sendmail
        @user = User.first
        UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
        render "user_mailer/welcome_email.text"
        #render the file to see what we're supposed to send
end
```

and this is the code in UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

```
 def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = "http://znood.com/"
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Welcome to Znood!") 
  end
```

This is the email I'm receiving:

```
Welcometoznood.com,AbdoAchkarYouhavesuccessfullysigneduptoznood.com,Yourusernameis:blabla.Tologintothesite,justfollowthislink:http://znood.com/.Thanksforjoiningandhaveagreatday!TheZnoodTeam
```

Any clue how to include the spaces, carriage returns and line feeds?

[edit]
After installing the letter_opener gem, I see the following in my console:

```
----==_mimepart_4ea9882a2735c_1c782d964bc18193

Date: Thu, 27 Oct 2011 19:34:50 +0300

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/plain;

 charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Content-ID: <4ea9882a2d8ee_1c782d964bc18277@lenovo-PC.mail>



Welcometoznood.com,AbdoAchkarYouhavesuccessfullysigneduptoznood.com,Yourusername
is:blabla.Tologintothesite,justfollowthislink:http://znood.com/.Thanksforjoiningandhaveagreatday!TheZnoodTeam
```

I attempting changing the "Content-Transfer-Encoding" headers but they don't seem to change. I also tried setting a default value for it. It looks like we're stuck with 7bit encoding.

[Edited]
Another that should help us find the problem is that I tried passing the following params to the mail function in order to see whether the file renderer is problematic:

```
   mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Welcome to Znood!") do |format|
        #format.text(:content_transfer_encoding => "base64")
        format.text { render :text => "Hello there!" }
    end
```

"Hellothere!" also came out collated.

I then tried the code below to make sure whether it's the render or mail function that's causing the errors.

```
mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Welcome to Znood!") do |format|
        format.text { "hello there!" }
end
```

Also came out collated.

Comment: What are the CRLF in the source template?

Comment: I don't know exactly but I think if we tackle the spaces problem and solve it, we'll solve the CRLF problem too =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me a while to resolve. The problem wasn't with ActionMailer.

If you're having this problem, first make sure it's not your code or gems causing this. Start a new rails application and test ActionMailer with it. (Thanks for @RubyCyanide for this suggestion)

In my case, it was a function `join` that I had in my `String class` initializer. It's very probable that you or a gem that you're using is conflicting with Mail's join function.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

By default, the mailer should be sending text emails--it's possible this is happening on the client side. The real solution is to have both text and HTML templates (or, through trickery (or just Markdown), use the same template for both, if they're equally simple.

Comment: I do have both, the text email is being rendered and I'm getting the email above. I tried having 1 file at a time and then tried having both. I keep having the same problem.

Comment: @Abdo It's still possible this is a client issue, plus I can't see what's in your HTML template (like does it actually contain HTML).

Comment: Agree with Dave here, maybe it's a client issue.

Comment: I installed the letter opener gem and got the same result.

Comment: @Abdo The letter opener gem is to see what's being sent, not to change it. View source.

Comment: @DaveNewton yup... What's being sent to the server according to the letter opener is the same as what's showing in my gmail.

Comment: @Abdo That... doesn't help diagnose anything; you know we can't see what's being sent, right? Check the mimetype.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think what Adbo is saying is that what appears in his gmail inbox and what letter opener shows (what rails sends) is identical meaning we've eliminated the possibility of a client side rendering / config issue. The problem must exist with a charset or mime type problem now.

Comment: @CaleyWoods exactly. I pasted above the output of letter_opener to my console.

Answer (score 0):

I'd setup a class that inherits from `ActionMailer::Base` and then create your `welcome_email` method there. Then in your controller call `FooMailer.welcome_email(@user.email).deliver`. If you are doing this a lot consider moving it to resque or delayed job.

As far as having an issue with the spacing, have you tried creating a `welcome_email.html.erb` and sending that out? You can specify in your `welcome_email` method to use the html (with or without a layout) like so:

```
def welcome_email(user)
  @user = user
  @url = "http://znood.com/"
  mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Welcome to Znood!") do |format|
    format.html #{ render :layout => 'my_layout' }
  end
end
```

You can watch Ryan Bates RailsCast  #206 [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3) to see this being used and also he shows a method of intercepting emails before they're delivered so you can see how they look. A more simple way of doing it is to use his [letter opener gem](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) it opens the email in the browser (use in dev mode).

Comment: Sorry, edited the code. This is what I have. I tried with different formats but it didn't work.

Comment: @Abdo I'd still put the letter opener gem in place and see what you're app is sending versus what you're seeing on the client (gmail, etc). Maybe it's not an app issue but a client configuration issue.

Comment: I installed the letter opener gem and got the same result. All the words collated to each others.

Comment: And that's when the email opens in the browser correct? You see all the words jumbled together? If letter opener is configured correctly using ```config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener``` in ```config/environments/development.rb``` any email delivered should open in the browser and NOT be delivered to the client.

Comment: Yes, @Caley. The file generated by the letter opener gem has all the words collated; the email isn't being sent to the client.

Comment: If you look at [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html), there are some options you can pass into the default in your UserMailer class. Perhaps encoding or something is off.

Comment: I tried ASCII as charset, still no dough.  I also tried having the same headers as http://rubydoc.info/gems/actionmailer/3.1.1/frames ... Same.